# Firebase Remote Config unable to remove condition from parameter

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase remote config where I have created parameters and assigned them values using conditions. After the latest Firebase update, I am unable to successfully remove any conditions assigned to parameters. When I remove the condition and save the changes and click on Publish Changes, the page is loaded and shows a popup message "published" but the condition is still present inside the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same. Only removal condition from conditions section helps.

Comment: I do not want to remove condition from the conditions section as that will create problems since it is used in other parameters too. I hope firebase resolves this quickly.